# Can't use output of the function as a react native element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**SOLVED** (a stupid mistake, check answers)

Currently, I'm rewriting my application from ReactJS to React Native and I step upon a problem with returning `<View>` `<Text>` elements by function. Here's my code:

```
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles.js";
import lessonPlan from "./lessonPlan.json";

const getFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    "jaapokki-regular": require("./assets/fonts/jaapokki-regular.ttf"),
    "jaapokki-enchance": require("./assets/fonts/jaapokkienchance-regular.ttf"),
    "jaapokki-substract": require("./assets/fonts/jaapokkisubtract-regular.ttf"),
  });
};

function OneLesson(props) {
  const { elementData } = props;
  const {
    noLessonsInTheSameTime,
    beginningTime,
    endingTime,
    subjectName,
    roomNumber,
  } = elementData;

  function moreLessons() {
    switch (noLessonsInTheSameTime) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <View style={styles.centerContent}>
            <Text style={styles.subject}>{subjectName[0]}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <View style={styles.centerContent}>
            <Text style={styles.subject}>{subjectName[0]}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.subject}>{subjectName[1]}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      default:
        return (
          <View style={styles.centerContent}>
            <Text style={styles.subject}>{subjectName[0]}</Text>
          </View>
        );
    }
  }
  function moreRooms() {
    switch (noLessonsInTheSameTime) {
      case 1:
        return (
          <View style={styles.sideContent}>
            <Text style={styles.room}>{roomNumber[0]}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <View style={styles.sideContent}>
            <Text style={styles.room}>{roomNumber[0]}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.room}>{roomNumber[1]}</Text>
          </View>
        );
      default:
        return (
          <View style={styles.sideContent}>
            <Text style={styles.room}>{roomNumber[0]}</Text>
          </View>
        );
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.sideContent}>
        <Text style={styles.beginningHour}>{beginningTime}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.endingHour}>{endingTime}</Text>
      </View>
      {moreLessons()}
      {moreRooms()}
    </View>
  );
}

function generateCard() {
  lessonPlan[0][0][1].map((el, i) => <OneLesson elementData={el} key={i} />);
}

export default function App() {
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false);

  if (fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.main}>
        <View style={styles.bottom}>
          <ScrollView
            style={styles.scrollBox}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            alwaysBounceVertical={true}
            decelerationRate={0.956}
            fadingEdgeLength={35}
          >
            <View style={styles.center}>{generateCard()}</View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={getFonts} onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)} />
    );
  }
}
```

I tried several things and the code above is the result of it. I also tried switching this function into `class App` and this not worked either.

The only thing that works is to nest mapping function into final return call in render method:

```
return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.main}>
        <View style={styles.bottom}>
          <ScrollView
            style={styles.scrollBox}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            alwaysBounceVertical={true}
            decelerationRate={0.956}
            fadingEdgeLength={35}
          >
            <View style={styles.center}>
              {
                <View style={styles.center}>
                  {lessonPlan[0][0][1].map((element) => (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                      <View style={styles.sideContent}>
                        <Text style={styles.beginningHour}>
                          {element.beginningTime}
                        </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.endingHour}>
                          {element.endingTime}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.centerContent}>
                        <Text style={styles.subject}>
                          {element.subjectName[0]}
                        </Text>
                      </View>
                      <View style={styles.sideContent}>
                        <Text style={styles.room}>{element.roomNumber[0]}</Text>
                      </View>
                    </View>
                  ))}
                </View>
              }
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

But this is not the way that satisfies me, because of this problem I'm limited in futher actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning from the function.

```
function generateCard() {
  // add return here
  return lessonPlan[0][0][1].map((el, i) => <OneLesson elementData={el} key={i} />);
}
```